# Completely locked out of the admin account with FreeIPA

Tags: ldap, freeipa

I have a FreeIPA server set up with a single replica. The admin account has been locked. Here's the log from a `kinit admin`:

```
[root@idm-00 ~]# kinit admin
kinit: Client's credentials have been revoked while getting initial credentials

Jun 26 13:04:08 idm-00.<REDACTED> krb5kdc[288805](info): AS_REQ (6 etypes {aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96(18), aes256-cts-hmac-sha384-192(20), camellia256-cts-cmac(26), aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96(17), aes128-cts-hmac-sha256-128(19), camellia128-cts-cmac(25)}) <REDACTED>: LOCKED_OUT: admin@<REDACTED> for krbtgt/<REDACTED>@<REDACTED>, Client's credentials have been revoked
```

I don't have another admin user on the system, but I do have root access to the server itself.

Is it possible to recover from this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are completely locked out of all administrator accounts, your next best bet is to use the LDAP directory manager password to [unlock the `admin` account](https://serverfault.com/questions/478041/accidentally-disabled-the-administrator-account-on-ipa-server).

If you do not have the directory manager password, but you do have root access to the FreeIPA server, there is a non-trivial process to [reset the LDAP directory manager password](https://www.port389.org/docs/389ds/howto/howto-resetdirmgrpassword.html) and then [update FreeIPA to utilize the new directory manager password](https://freeipa.org/page/Howto/Change_Directory_Manager_Password).  Once you have the directory manager password, you should be able to unlock the `admin` account.

Some notes to alleviate this problem in the future:

If you have any FreeIPA bits (UI, LDAP, SSH) publicly accessible for any enrolled server, they are very likely to be probed.  Since the `admin` user is enabled by default, there are usually many brute force attempts to gain access which will lock the account.  To avoid fighting to constantly unlock the `admin` account, it is usually good practice to disable or remove the default `admin` account and assign non-default users as `admins`.

You may also want more than one administrator user, or another user that has permissions to modify lockout state.  This makes it easier to [unlock accounts](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/identity_management_guide/user-unlock) as long as at least one of the capable users is available.

Comment: Along with granting admin rights to additional accounts, I took steps to ensure the `admin` user's password would not expire unexpectedly.  In essence, I created a group for the `admin` user, created a custom password expiration policy and associated it with that group, made the `admin` user a member of the group, and changed the `admin` user's password.  The sequence of the last two steps made sure the group's policy was applied to the new password, so it wouldn't expire at another, unexpected time.